# Google Map - Load map when place found

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

This is the code I'm working from. Is it possible to only load up the map when the user has actually selected a place.

http://jsfiddle.net/2q8Pw/

For example, someone might type in "Lond" and then select "London" from the list, at the point at which google geocodes the result, is the point at which the map is shown with the right location.

What is the best way something like this could be achieved?

Comment: is this http://jsfiddle.net/2q8Pw/6/ you want

Comment: Thats really sweet. Can we have it so the box doesnt even show before there is a place (at the moment, it is grey). Can you also put this as an answer so I can award it.

Comment: with pleasure.., I put my changes as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove center while creating map object. map will not show till you set center of map. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2q8Pw/6/)

```
var mapOptions = {             
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
```